# .parents() without jquery - or querySelectorAll for parents

Tags: javascript, parent, selectors-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check event.target.parentElement with matchesSelector js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977658/check-event-target-parentelement-with-matchesselector-js)

I have a dom object, I'd like to match its parents, all parents, against a selector, like `querySelectAll()`, but for parents instead of children. Similar to jQuery's `.parents('selector')` method, but I do NOT need any back-wards compatibility. Also, no libraries please. I will totes take a boolean return value.

I CAN write this myself as a recursive function/for/while using `matchesSelector()`. I'm looking for little-known methods or more efficient code.

Saving any processing is worth it. Think tens of thousands of match checks, or more even.

Comment: Where is said-code you wrote yourself? (so that people can help point out flaws / add improvements)

Comment: This looks like the same issue you asked about earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977658/check-event-target-parentelement-with-matchesselector-js

Comment: @user1689607 Ha! Yeah looks that way... I was thinking slightly differently here. I had forgotten about jQuery's parents method. Sigh... been staring at the same code for so long I've forgotten the rest of the world exist...

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS I said I COULD, not that I have. But I imagine 
`
for()
`

Comment: `for(x=0;x<parents.length;x++){if(parents[x].matchesSelector('selector')){return:true;}} `

Comment: Sorry, can you please expand on why you've marked @MarkPieszak as the correct answer as it doesn't appear to cater for the "upward selector" aspect you are asking for. From what I can make out he is simply returning a selected node's direct family tree. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Pancho Because he wanted *all* parents UP from a selector. I updated the answer to include an optional 2nd parameter where you can also select where you want it to **stop** adding parents to the Array. :)

Comment: [`Element::closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You would want to use a `while()` loop since we don't know the exact number of parents we have

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wtgxry0v/)**

```
function getParents(el, parentSelector /* optional */) {

    // If no parentSelector defined will bubble up all the way to *document*
    if (parentSelector === undefined) {
        parentSelector = document;
    }

    var parents = [];
    var p = el.parentNode;
    
    while (p !== parentSelector) {
        var o = p;
        parents.push(o);
        p = o.parentNode;
    }
    parents.push(parentSelector); // Push that parentSelector you wanted to stop at
    
    return parents;
}
```

#### Useage: Returns an Array of "parents"

```
// 2nd param optional, bubbles up to document
getParents( document.getElementById('me') ); 

// get all parents starting from -me- up to ID -outerParent-
getParents( document.getElementById('me'), document.getElementById('outerParent') );
```