# Javascript get similar elements without jQuery

Tags: javascript

i have something like this :

```
<li id="test">
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />

</li>

<li id="test2">
    <div id="special">
        <input type="text" name="city" />
        <input type="text" name="pc" />
   </div>
</li>
```

When a user clicks on one input, I'd like to get all `li`s with an `input` child.  For example, if a user clicks on `.pc`, I'd like to return both `#test` and `#test2`.  I cannot use jQuery or any other external libraries.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the closest 'li' parent?

Comment: yes, i want to get all of 'li' parent of each input

Comment: Okay, so you want every `li` with an `input` child whenever a user clicks on an `input`?

Comment: yes, but only in javascript if it's possible.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to do something a library can do without using the library, it's a good idea to look at the library's source (here's jQuery's: https://github.com/jquery/jquery).  I'll go through and try to parse that into a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

for the second one (test2 in pc), you could use

```
$('#pc').closest('li');
```

to grab the closest parent of type li. (this would return just test2)

If you want both, however, you could give them a unique class (or something to help pick them out), and you could use

```
$('#pc').parents('li.myclass');
```

as an example

Edit: these are assuming also that you only want these two tests. If you want all of the li's, you could just use

```
$('#pc').parents('li');
```

Edit2: If it is not possible to use JQuery, there is a method someone wrote to handle this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980877/parents-without-jquery-or-queryselectorall-for-parents)

Comment: OP didn't say he can use jQuery, and didn't add the tag. Try not using jQuery in answers then.

Comment: ok thx, i will try it, and indeed, i don't want to use jQUery.

Comment: ok, yea try the second edit then. I should have checked first if you were comfortable with using JQuery haha.

Comment: $('#pc') wouldn't even select anything the OP provided. The selector for that element would need to be $('input[name="pc"]'), and then this isn't returning what the OP asked for, all lis with an input as a child.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reason jQuery is around...

You could start with looping over `document.getElementsByTagName('li')` then loop through the children, looking for an element with a `tagName === 'INPUT'` and then loop through the children's children etc.

Or go the other way checking parent from all inputs as in this answer -> [How to check in Javascript if one element is contained within another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234979/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-one-element-is-a-child-of-another)