# How to use the parentNode property multiple times?

Tags: javascript, parent-node

I have a question. How can I use the parentNode property multiple times?

I know that I can make something like this:

```
document.getElementById("mytag").parentNode.parentNode.remove();
```

Or something like this. My Problem is not that I can add more or less .parentNode to remove whatever I want to remove.

My Problem is that I want to create a user friendly app in which the user can self declare how many parentNodes should be removed.

At first I tried to add .parentNode by a loop. It doesn't work. At second I tried the same with the eval() function. Same result.

Is there a person who have a good solution how I can make this? It was very useful if there is a opportunity on which you only have to say the number of parentNodes.

Here a little example. What I will be done "automatically":

```
myFunction(..., ..., 3) {
    ...
    document.getElementById("mytag").parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

Or

```
myFunction(..., ..., 2) {
    ...
    document.getElementById("mytag").parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

Or

```
myFunction(..., ..., 1) {
    ...
    document.getElementById("mytag").parentNode.remove();
}
```

Thank you very much.

I prefere a solution in pure JS. An additional jQuery solution would be also nice.

Comment: You tagged jQuery but you're not using it, and did not mention accepting a jQuery-based solution—if that is the case, the tag shouldn't be used.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980877/parents-without-jquery-or-queryselectorall-for-parents

Answer (score 2):

This function should do the job:

```
function removeParent(element, num) {
    var parent = element;
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        if (parent.parentNode) {
            parent = parent.parentNode;
        }
    }
    parent.remove();
}
```

You can test it on this page. For example, the stackoverflow logo. HTML structure is like this:

```
HTML
    HEAD
    BODY
        DIV.container
            DIV#header
                DIV#hlogo
```

Open the console, copy-paste the function, and then enter `removeParent(hlogo, 4)`. Entire page will disappear :)