# What is the pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's .parents() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-translation

Apologies for this kind of question, but I can't find an answer on [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) or anywhere else online and I'd really like to know:

**What is the pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's .parents() method?**

For example, it would be great to know how to do this in pure JavaScript:

```
jQuery(element).parents('.className');
```

Comment: *"What is the pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's .parents() method?"* There is none. Do you mean "What's the DOM API version of jQuery's `parents()` method?"

Comment: `while ((element = element.parentElement)) { if (element.matches('.className')) { result.push(element) } }`

Comment: I was pretty sure this is a duplicate but I can't find it.

Comment: You can always look at jQuery's github for their source: [.parents()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/305f193aa57014dc7d8fa0739a3fefd47166cd44/src/traversing.js#L115) -> [dir()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/traversing/var/dir.js)

Comment: Ah, yes [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12980877/1048572) is what I was looking for

Comment: I went straight to their github and searched, but it seems "bitten" did have an answer below that also listed the transversing module

Answer (score 8):

There is no one function/property in the DOM API that equates to jQuery's `parents()`. There is the `parentNode` property (and as [Oriol points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469830/what-is-the-pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-parents-method/38469853#comment64343788_38469853), the `parentElement` property, which will prevent your going from `document.documentElement` up to `document`), which is the parent node (or parent element) of the element on which you access it, or `null` if it doesn't have one. To roughly match jQuery's `parents()`, you can loop on it (e.g., get the `parentNode`/`parentElement` of the `parentNode`/`parentElement`, etc.) to find all the parents. As [squint notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469830/what-is-the-pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-parents-method-no-answer#comment64343642_38469830), on vaguely-modern browsers at each level you can use [`matches`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector) to check if the parent matches a selector (to match jQuery's behavior with `parents()` when you pass it a selector).

jQuery takes a set-based approach to DOM manipulation and traversal, whereas the DOM API takes a per-element/node approach.

Example:

```js
var elm = document.getElementById("target");
var parents = getParents(elm);
console.log(Array.prototype.map.call(
  parents,
  function(e) {
    return e.nodeName + (e.id ? "#" + e.id : "");
  }
).join(", "));
function getParents(e) {
  var result = [];
  for (var p = e && e.parentElement; p; p = p.parentElement) {
    result.push(p);
  }
  return result;
}
```

```html
<div id="outermost">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      <div id="target"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Use `parentElement` instead of `parentNode` to avoid `document`.

Comment: @Oriol: That requires more modern browsers than `matches`/`matchesSelector` though

Comment: @Bergi Maybe, if you consider non-standard names with vendor prefixes. `parentElement` doesn't need that, and has much more support than `matches`.

Comment: @Oriol: Ooops, right, I mixed `matchesSelector` with `matches` support.

Answer (score 2):

## Node.parentNode

When you get a HTML via some method (`document.getElementById()`, `document.querySelector()`, etc) it will return a Node object, the `.parentNode` property of the object is the parent Node object

---

**To get all parent nodes, akin to jQuery's `.parents()`:**

I wrote this function a while back:

```
function parents(node) {
   let current = node,
       list    = [];
   while(current.parentNode != null && current.parentNode != document.documentElement) {
     list.push(current.parentNode);
     current = current.parentNode;
   }
    return list
}
```

Please note this is only slightly tested, so take it with a grain of salt

Comment: Not really the same thing, although you can recursively traverse the DOM backwards using the .parentNode property to achieve similar functionality to the jQuery .parents() method.  But it requires writing some code.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't downvote based on that, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Agreed.  Reversed the downvote, to harsh :-)

Comment: Using `parentElement` there is no need to check `!= document`.

Comment: You need to make sure `current` isn't `null` before accessing `.parentNode`.

Comment: Isn't the `parentElement` of `body` the document?

Comment: It's the `document.documentElement`.

Comment: Ok. See? Very little tested. I will update the function accordingly

Comment: I wrote it recursively originally, than make it just loop