# Call 'second child' element using 'first child' element of a common 'parent element' in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.child_1').parents('.parent').find('.child_2')
```

How do I call the above JQuery syntax using core javascript syntax?

I am calling the `child_2` using `child_1` who has a common `parent`

Answer (score 0):

`$('.child_1').closest('.parent').find('.child_2');`

`closest()` will get you the first parent that matches the given query string.

Comment: OP is asking how to do this in javascript

Comment: It is javascript of course, and he also included the `jquery` tag, so I think this is appropriate.

Comment: "How do I call the above JQuery syntax using Javascript syntax?" The question is clear

Comment: By JS, he means vanilla JS

Comment: In my case, i can only provide ID to child_1, and it has to call to child_2 using a parent, both not having any ID

Comment: Then a class approach when the `id` is unknown is correct, like `$('#child_1').closest('.parent').find('.child_2');`, with `#` denoting the id and `.` denoting a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('.child_1').parents('.parent:first').find('.class:eq(1)');
```

First notice that I have used `:first` to determine the proper parent of the child_1.
Then,
I have put in `eq(1)` because child counting starts from 0;

Comment: OP is asking how to do this in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer to [Get parents of element in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980877/parents-without-jquery-or-queryselectorall-for-parents) and then iterate over the parents to get their child using `querySelector`

```
var parents = getParents( document.getElementByClassName('.child_1')[0]);
var children = [];

parents.forEach(function (parent) {
    children.push(parent.querySelector('.child_2'));
});
```

Comment: This example was not entirely clear to me. 
In my case, i can only provide ID to child_1, and it has to call to child_2 using a parent, both not having any ID

Comment: @AtulKumar didn't get what you require

Comment: The answer is almost complete, but I think you also need a way to specify which parent, by using a class maybe `.parent`, if the id is not available.

Comment: @CatalinIancu Yes, but according to jQuery provided in question, it is asking for parents, not parent

Comment: @DeepanshSachdeva close to what you suggested. Yes, I do have to specify which parent I need to go.
I guess it is close, but gives an error, parents is not a function.

Comment: I think the function `getParents()` is not a JS standard function, so you need to define what it does.

Comment: @Catalinlancu that function is from the answer I mentioned in mine answer.

Comment: @AtulKumar edit the question with the details about what you want to do along with an example. It would help in resolving your issue more quickly.