# jQuery Selectors with React is ok?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I know mixing jQuery and ReactJS is not advisable, because ReactJS is not aware of any modifications to the DOM made by jQuery. But what if you only use jQuery for querying the DOM and finding nodes easily and conveniently, while leaving all the DOM editing to ReactJS. Other than jQuery being a big library, are there any other downsides to this?

An example use case is setting up event listeners whenever a dropdown menu component mounts that check to see if the user clicks anywhere off the menu, so that the menu can close. The jQuery `.parents()` method is a very convenient way to check if the the click target is a child of the menu container element. Is there an easy way to do this in `ReactJS` or with `vanilla JavaScript`?

Here is a code sample of this example:

```
handleClick = e => {
  const element = $(e.target)
  if( !( element.parents('.menu').length || element.hasClass('menu'))) {
    this.setState({ menuOpen: false })
  }
}

componentWillUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
  if(nextState.menuOpen && !this.state.menuOpen) {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false)
  } else if (!nextState.menuOpen && this.state.menuOpen) {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you only want jQuery's selector engine, look into using [Sizzle](https://sizzlejs.com/) or [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/). If you are not worry about backwards compatibility with older, non-evergreen browsers, [try this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980877/parents-without-jquery-or-queryselectorall-for-parents).

Comment: Checkout https://sizzlejs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say there are disadvantages to using jQuery in React.

**The VDOM diffing algorithm will get confused**

This is one that you mentioned. Yes, it will be fine if you use only `read-only` attributes, but unless you're targeting older browsers something like [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) would be lighter weight.

Every depedency you're bringing in, especially as one as large as library, should be meticulously vetted. See [the website obesity epedemic](http://idlewords.com/talks/website_obesity.htm) for details.

In addition, the idea of "I will only use it for reading and let React do the rest" will add a significant layer of confusion to your code, as we'll see in the next example.

**You abandon the patterns of React**

In my opinion, the bigger issue is abandoning the patterns of React. To describe React in one sentence, I would say:

*React is a component-based library used to generate HTML, CSS, and JavaScript functionality derived from `state` inputs.*

Let's say I have a simple `UserProfile` component. This component will have some data about the user, including a switch to receive push notifications or not:

```
// Please note this is simplified pseudo-code, and will likely not work
class UserProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Bob',
    profilePic: 'someurl.com/profile-pic',
    isReceivingNotifications: false
  }

  updateReceivingNotifications = () => {
    this.setState({ isReceivingNotifications: !this.state.isReceivingNotifications })
  }

  render() {
    const { name, profilePic, isReceivingNotifcations } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <img src={profilePic} />
        <input type="checkbox" checked={isReceivingNotifications} onChange={this.updateReceivingNotifications} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Simple, the component presentation is derived from the state of the component. If the `isReceivingNotifcations` is true, then the checkbox will be checked.

Let's look at this same example with the proposed design pattern:

```
class UserProfile extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Bob',
    profilePic: 'someurl.com/profile-pic',
    isReceivingNotifications: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const checkBox = document.getElementById('my-checkbox');
    const that = this;
    // Use a regular function to bind the this context to the checkbox instead of component
    checkBox.addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.checked) {
         that.setState({ isReceivingNotifcations: true });
      } else {
         that.setState({ isReceivingNotifcations: false });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { name, profilePic, isReceivingNotifcations } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <img src={profilePic} />
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={isReceivingNotifications}
          id="my-checkbox"
          />
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The first is much cleaner, no matter how you format this with jQuery or whatever DOM manipulation library you would use.

This is a contrived example, but every time I've seen some version of this in real life it's been quite a mess.

**In the end, why?**

Just take a bit of time and learn React design patterns. I'd suggest [thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html). jQuery should be a last resort, as you're using React for a reason i'd assume.

**One exception to this is jQuery libraries you use in React**

In this case, you have no other option other than rewriting the library. As highlighted in [this article](http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/) you should write a wrapper component to make it React compliant.

Comment: Of course for components where all user interactions are contained within that component, DOM queries are unnecessary. But what if you need a component to be aware of a click that happened outside of it? There are HOCs you can find that check if the click happened outside, but they probably use DOM queries internally themselves. Maybe not JQuery but a DOM query none-the-less. And more so, what if the requirement is even more complicated? What if I need to know if the click happened in some specific component outside of the current one? The react implementation would be so complex

Comment: I would say that is using the less common scenario to justify a more common one. The less common scenario is component actions outside of the component (modals, menus, etc). Now, we have [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) to take care of this exact scenario.

Comment: we use React because it is mainstream and hype in great part, I assume

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in saying your question boils down to: is it OK to query the browser DOM for information that you will use in React?
Since the virtual DOM is always synced with the browser DOM, doing read-only lookups in the browser DOM is certainly not bad. In fact, if you want to add interactivity or user event handling, you'll sometimes need to do this on the browser DOM instead of the virtual DOM.

Then as for which library to use: besides jQuery there are lighter options like minifiedjs.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am checking to see if there are any pitfalls to doing browser DOM lookups with a jQuery like library. Your suggestion is that there aren't any major ones if any at all, so it is ok. I will wait to see if anyone can come up with anything else, otherwise I will mark yours as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: One thing to note here is that React already has an [API for accessing](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html) the DOM, which you should prefer over something like jQuery.