# pure Javascript get parents

Tags: javascript

I created a snippet based on [.parents() without jquery - or querySelectorAll for parents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980877/parents-without-jquery-or-queryselectorall-for-parents)

```js
  function getParents (el, _class) {
    let doc = document
    let parents = []
    let p = el.parentNode

    while (p !== doc) {
      let o = p
      parents.push(o)
      p = o.parentNode
    }
    parents.push(doc)
    return parents[parents.map(x => x.className).indexOf(_class)]
  }

document.querySelectorAll('.child1').forEach((e,i)=>{
  console.log(getParents(e, 'child4'))
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4 hello">  <!-- problem here -->
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

if `<div class="child4 hello">` without `hello` I can get all `child4`, if `hello` or anything else is added, I am unable to get `child4`. I use `indexOf()` I think shouldn't be `-1` or undefined. Could someone please correct me where is the error? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `parents.map(x => x.className)` you will get an array with the full class string for each element. So the result will look like (simplified) `[ "child4 hello" ]` and you try to do `indexOf("child4")` on that *array*. Since there is no member that is simply `"child4"`, that fails.

Here is the problematic code illustrated:

```js
function getParents (el, _class) {
    let doc = document
    let parents = []
    let p = el.parentNode

    while (p !== doc) {
      let o = p
      parents.push(o)
      p = o.parentNode
    }
    parents.push(doc)
    let mappedClassName = parents.map(x => x.className)
    console.log("mappedClassName", mappedClassName)
    let indexOf = mappedClassName.indexOf(_class);
    console.log("indexOf", indexOf)
    return parents[indexOf]
  }

document.querySelectorAll('.child1').forEach((e,i)=>{
  console.log(getParents(e, 'child4'))
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4 hello">  <!-- problem here -->
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code would work with a *string*:

```js
let indexOf = "child4 hello".indexOf("child4");
console.log(indexOf);
```

However, it doesn't necessarily work *correctly*:

```js
//the class is NOT child4
let indexOf = "child42 hello".indexOf("child4");
console.log(indexOf);
```

You should use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for a more accurate class check:

```js
let div1 = document.getElementById("one");
let div2 = document.getElementById("two");

let _class = "child4";
console.log(`div1 has ${_class}`, div1.classList.contains(_class))
console.log(`div2 has ${_class}`, div2.classList.contains(_class))
```

```html
<div id="one" class="child4 hello"></div>
<div id="two" class="child42 hello"></div>
```

If you combine this with [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to achieve what you want:

```js
function getParents (el, _class) {
    let doc = document
    let parents = []
    let p = el.parentNode

    while (p !== doc) {
      let o = p
      parents.push(o)
      p = o.parentNode
    }
    parents.push(doc)
    return parents[parents.map(x => x.classList).findIndex(cl => cl.contains(_class))]
    //                                ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^
  }

document.querySelectorAll('.child1').forEach((e,i)=>{
  console.log(getParents(e, 'child4'))
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4 hello">  <!-- problem here -->
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can make the code slightly shorter by dropping `.map` and running the logic in `.findIndex`:

```
parents.findIndex(x => x.classList.contains(_class))
```

However, with all that said, your algorithm only checks *classes*. You can very easily extend it to work with any selector by using [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches):

```js
function getParents (el, selector) {
    let doc = document
    let parents = []
    let p = el.parentNode

    while (p !== doc) {
      let o = p
      parents.push(o)
      p = o.parentNode
    }
    parents.push(doc)
    return parents[parents.findIndex(x => x instanceof Element && x.matches(selector))]
    // only check Elements -------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              
  }

document.querySelectorAll('.child1').forEach((e,i)=>{
  console.log('.child4', getParents(e, '.child4'))
})


document.querySelectorAll('.child1').forEach((e,i)=>{
  console.log('#parentTwo.child4', getParents(e, '#parentTwo.child4'))
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div id="parentOne" class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div id="parentTwo" class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div id="parentThree" class="child4 hello">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're getting a list of elements and you're mapping those to the elements' `className`, when the target element have more then just the `child4` class, the value in the array will be `child4 hello` and when you're looking for the index of the `child4` value in the array, the `child4 hello` won't match. Instead of `Array.indexOf` you can use `Array.find`.

```js
  function getParents (el, _class) {
    let doc = document
    let parents = []
    let p = el.parentNode

    while (p !== doc) {
      let o = p
      parents.push(o)
      p = o.parentNode
    }
    parents.push(doc)
    return parents.find(e => e.className.includes(_class))
  }

document.querySelectorAll('.child1').forEach((e,i)=>{
  console.log(getParents(e, 'child4'))
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4 hello">  <!-- problem here -->
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of the `getParents` function you could use [Element.closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Here is an example:

```js
const parents = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.child1')).map(e => e.closest('.child4'));
console.log(parents);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4 hello">
      <!-- problem here -->
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As @Khauri mentioned, in the first example, instead of using the `className` property and using string functions to check if that value is a match, it will be better to use the `classList` property because it has a `contains` function.

Comment: [`classList.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is better here. `className.includes` would return true when searching for class names that include substrings rather than the specific class. "child" in child4 for example

Answer (score 2):

You could use `findIndex` of Array prototype like so :
`return parents[parents.map(x => x.className).findIndex(x => x.indexOf(_class) > -1)]`

```js
function getParents (el, _class) {
    let doc = document
    let parents = []
    let p = el.parentNode

    while (p !== doc) {
      let o = p
      parents.push(o)
      p = o.parentNode
    }
    parents.push(doc)
    return parents[parents.map(x => x.className).findIndex(x => x.indexOf(_class) > -1)]
  }

document.querySelectorAll('.child1').forEach((e,i)=>{
  console.log(getParents(e, 'child4'))
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4 hello">  <!-- problem here -->
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) to add support to `query` the `parents`

```js
function getParents(el, query) {
  let parents = []
  while (el.parentNode !== document.body) {
    el.matches(query) && parents.push(el)
    el = el.parentNode
  }
  return parents
}

document.querySelectorAll('.child1').forEach((e, i) => {
  console.log(getParents(e, '.child4'))
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4">
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="parent">
  <div class="child5">
    <div class="child4 hello">
      <!-- problem here -->
      <div class="child3">
        <div class="child2">
          <div class="child1">
            3
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```